# Is the following schema a derived rule of our logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is the following schema a derived rule of our logic?

$$ A \rightarrow B \vdash A \rightarrow (\forall x)B, \text{ provided $x$ is not free in $A$ }$$

If yes, then give a proof. if no, show why by proving the invalid "strong generalization" using the above formula.

This question is in **Ex 2** of Section 8.3 of *Mathematical Logic* by G.Tourlakis, page 208.

I don't understand what proving invalid "Strong generalization" has to do with proving invalidity of a rule.

The following is the solution for this question which I don't understand.

$$ (1)\ A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle\text{hypothesis}\rangle $$
$$ (2)\ T \rightarrow A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle(1) + \vdash A \equiv (T \rightarrow A) + Eqn\rangle$$
$$ (3)\ T \rightarrow  (\forall x)A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle(2) + \text{above rule}\rangle$$
$$(4)\ (\forall x)A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle(3) + \vdash X \equiv (T \rightarrow X)\rangle$$

Comment: Must be : "$x$ not free in $A$".

Comment: About "strong generalization", the hint of the book gives as the "implicit suggestion" that the "rule" of the exercise is not sound. See page 147, where the "strong generalization" rule (i.e.$A/(\forall x)A$) is discussed : it is not *sound* in the system. Assume now that the "rule" of the Exrecise is sound: then, with $A$ in place of $B$, from the *tautology* $A \rightarrow A$, we may derive : $\vdash A \rightarrow (\forall x)A$. Thus: from $A$, $(\forall x)A$ follows, i.e.the "unsound" *strong generalization*.

Comment: For the discussion about the "unsoundness" of *strong generalization*, see also page 157 and page 205.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement of the Exercise gives us two hints :

> > If you do not think [that it is a derived rule of our logic] then give a definitive reason as to *why* — for example, using a concrete interpretation, or by proving the invalid "strong generalization" using [it] as a lemma.

We may try with the counter-example, i.e. finding an *interpretation* [see page 197] in the domain $\mathbb N$ of the *natural numbers* such that the above formula is *false* [see **Example 8.1.7**, page 200, and also page 143].

Let $A$ is $0 = 0$ ($x$ is not *free* in it), and let $B$ is $x = 0$.

We have that $A \rightarrow B$ is :

> $0 = 0 \rightarrow (x = 0)$.

If we assign to $x$ the *denotation* $0$, we have that $A \rightarrow B$ is *true*, but of course $A \rightarrow (\forall x)B$ (which is : $0 = 0 \rightarrow (\forall x)(x = 0)$) is obviously *false* in $\mathbb N$.

Now we have to apply **2.6.1 Metatheorem. (Deduction Theorem)** :

> if $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then also $\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$ [page 81]

and **8.2.3 Metatheorem. (Soundness in First-Order Logic)** :

> if $\vdash A$, then $\vDash A$.

**If** our formula would be a "sound" rule, we would have (by the *Deduction Theorem*, with $\Gamma = \emptyset$) that :

> $\vdash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow (\forall x)B)$.

Thus, by *Soundness* :

> $\vDash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow (\forall x)B)$.

But we have found a counter-example, i.e. an *interpreation* where the formula is *false*; thus, it cannot be *universally valid* (that is: *true* in **all** interpretations - see page 201).

Comment: Thank you for your help :)